# Set value to multiple <select> tags in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

Im trying to set value to multiple `<select>` tags as shown in below picture.
`<select>` tags are not getting selected, everything looks fine.

What im missing??

**HTML:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in tab track by $index">
<td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
<td>{{ t.name }}</td>
<td>{{ t.phno }}</td>
<td>{{ t.email }}</td>
<td>{{ t.type }}</td>
<td data-ng-show="user_type=='student' || user_type=='all'">{{ t.class_name }}</td>
<td data-ng-show="user_type=='student' || user_type=='all'">{{ t.section_name }}</td>
<td data-ng-show="user_type=='student' || user_type=='all'">
    <select data-ng-show="t.type=='Student'" ng-model="plan_id">
        <option value=''>--SELECT--</option>
        <option ng-repeat="price in pricingList" data-ng-selected="{{t.plan_id == price.plan_id}}" value="{{price.plan_id}}">{{price.plan_name}}</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td data-ng-show="msg=='s'"><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="t.selected" value="{{t.id}}" data-ng-checked="Sall"></td>
<td data-ng-show="msg=='r'">{{t.status}}</td>
<td data-ng-show="user_type=='student' || user_type=='all'">
    <button type="button" data-ng-show="t.type=='Student'" ng-click="updatePlan(plan_id, t.id);">Update</button>
</td>
```

**JS:**

```
    $scope.pricingList = [{"plan_id":1,"plan_name":"Free"},{"plan_id":2,"plan_name":"Basic"}];

    var URL=appURL+'/adm/loadSMSCollege.do';
    var json={"type":$scope.user_type, "class_id":$scope.class_id, "section_id":$scope.section_id, "created_by":$cookieStore.get("loginBean").created_by};
    $http.post(URL, JSON.stringify(json)).then(function(response){
        $scope.tab = response.data;
        $scope.len = response.data.length;
    });
```

**Sample View:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` also change model to `t.plan_id`

```
 <td data-ng-show="user_type=='student' || user_type=='all'">
   <select data-ng-show="t.type=='Student'" ng-model="t.plan_id" ng-options="price.plan_id as price.plan_name for price in pricingList">
      <option value=''>--SELECT--</option>

</select>
 </td>
```

Comment: works perfectly.. i will add u +1 when i get an eligibility.. thank you